# Estimate event probability from yes/no data

Tags: probability, logistic, predictive-models, scoring-rules, vowpal-wabbit

I need to predict (estimate) probabilities of (rare) events when the training data only contains the yes/no indicator.

I.e., my target (dependent) variable is binary (logical).

What I need is not just to predict yes/no, but estimate the probabilities of yes/no for each observation.

If I use logistic regression, then the model output is, indeed, an estimate of the probability. What if I am using a different model, e.g., `vw`? (because, e.g., it is faster and outperforms logistic regression as a binary classifier).

**So, I have a model which produces a score for each observation and I want to convert the score to probability.**

It is natural to use [total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) to evaluate the probability prediction, which motivated [my previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99738/how-do-i-train-a-logistic-regression-in-r-using-l1-loss-function). The accepted answer there suggests Liblinear with L1 loss, but that produces a binary classifier, not a probability estimator.

So, how do I calibrate model scores so that they actually estimate the event probabilities?

I now train a single-independent-variable logistic regression to map the scores to probabilities. Can I do better?

Comment: If you check among my questions you can find how to extract a probability from a decision tree classifier. It is reported in the book the elements of statistical learning. Sorry but I'm on a tablet can't give you the link

Comment: I think you're referring to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93202/odds-ratio-from-decision-tree-and-random-forest

Comment: yes is this one. Let me know if this can help