# The intuition behind the different scoring rules

Tags: logistic, intuition, rare-events, scoring-rules

Consider the three [scoring rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) in the case of a binary prediction:

1. Log: `sum(log(ifelse(outcome, probability, 1-probability))) / n`
2. Brier: `sum((outcome-probability)**2) / n`
3. Sphere: `sum(ifelse(outcome, probability, 1-probability)/sqrt(probability**2+(1-probability)**2)) / n`

What is the *intuition* behind them? When should I use one and not the other?
I am especially interested in the case of low prevalence (e.g., 0.1%).

PS. This is to evaluate the results from [my calibration algorithm which I asked about before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99870/13538).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Justifying and choosing a proper scoring rule](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126965/justifying-and-choosing-a-proper-scoring-rule)

Comment: do you think your own post is a duplicate? As I read the linked thread, it does not (currently) answer all the questions I understand in your Q here. I would not vote to close, as I would be interested in answers to your questions (+1 from before). But you can always delete your own Q, if you want.

Comment: @gung: I would love to see an answer too, but the referenced question and its answer is highly related and I wanted to point that out. I think a "possible dupe" is a good way, especially since you clearly indicated your disagreement (thank you!) and thus made the actual closing unlikely. :-)

Comment: You can simply add a comment to your Q w/ a link saying that it is related or may also be of interest to readers. That would accomplish what you set out to do here. I would not flag your Q for closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Regarding only 1. the intuition is that it is the log likelihood function for a binary outcome Y which we know has certain optimality properties when maximized to fit statistical models.

Answer (score 2):

One place where log scoring may be inappropriate: the comparison of human forecasters (who may tend to overstate their confidence).

Log scoring strongly penalizes very overconfident wrong predictions. A wrong prediction that was made with 100% confidence gets an infinite penalty. For example, suppose a commentator says "I am 100% sure that Smith will win the election," and then Smith loses the election. Under log scoring, the average score of all the commentator's predictions is now permanently stuck at $-\infty$, the worst possible. It should be possible to distinguish that somebody who has made a single wrong 100% confidence prediction is a better forecaster than somebody who makes them all the time.

Comment: I would say that "over-penalizing over-confidence" is a _feature_, not a _bug_.

Answer (score 1):

## Log

The expected [surprisal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-information) of the prediction when we discover the actual value.

## Brier

$L^2$, [RMSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), OLS.

However, the fact that $p=2$ is the [only](http://www.nssl.noaa.gov/users/brooks/public_html/feda/note/properscoring.html) value which turns the $L^p$ norm into  proper scoring rule detracts from this intuition.

## Sphere

The cosine of the angle between the prediction vector $(p,1-p)$ and the outcome vector (0,1) or (1,0).

Note that the [angle](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/152255/13538) itself is not a *proper* scoring rule, which also detracts from the intuition.

Comment: Although you answered your own question, your answer is incoherent as a response to your interesting question. For example, "Log: the expected surprisal of the prediction when we discover the actual value" is incoherent as an answer to the question, "What is the intuition behind them? When should I use one and not the other?"

Comment: @Tripartio: do you have a better answer?

Comment: No I don't. I upvoted the question because I would really like to learn the answer. However, I posted a related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495935/non-mathematical-explanation-of-how-to-interpret-and-evaluate-scoring-rules-in-r