# Is the "angle=arccos(spherical)" scoring rule strictly proper?

Tags: scoring-rules

The [Spherical scoring rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Spherical_scoring_rule) is known to be strictly proper.

However, it is not very intuitive.

Its `arccos`, however, is the angle between the prediction `(p,1-p)` and actual outcome `(a,1-a)` vectors (where `a=1` or `a=0`).

**Is it strictly proper?** (`arccos` is decreasing, so we need to replace `min` with `max` in the definition, which is fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is *not*:

[image: sphere]

[image: angle]

as one can see, 0.2 is the only max for the spherical rule, but it is not the max for the angle.

The intuition is that the angle has the wrong balance between "left" and "right" parts: it grows to fast on the left and drops too slowly on the right.